# Adding additional attributes to the <table> prevents the class attribute from rendering

Tags: django-tables2

I am using the Bootstrap template which renders the `<table>` tag with a class, like this: `<table class="table">`.

I would like to add an id attribute to the `<table>` element. I tried this from my views.py:

```
t = MyTable(data, attrs={'id':'myid'})
```

This resulted in the id attribute being output as expected but the and the class attribute was removed. Looking at bootstrap.html I see why:

```
<table {% if table.attrs %} {{ table.attrs.as_html }}{% else %}class="table"{% endif %}>
```

I see two possible fixes:

1. Include `{"class": "table"}` in the attributes array. This should work but I need to remember to do it each time and the view then is doing the job of the template.
2. Create a new copy of the bootstrap.html template that always outputs `class="table"` regardless of the attributes passed in. This is better but I'm left wondering why the template author put that 'if' statement in.

Is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this doesn't have a nice solution currently. I don't like to do 2, but I don't like to require 1 too.

I'm thinking to solve this by having `'class': 'table'` in `attrs` by default. Just did not have the time to fix this properly yet.

Comment: I've gone with 2 (for now), using this in my template:

    <table class="table" {{ table.attrs.as_html }} >